# vue-javascript-can't evoke mousemove event after passing argument value

Tags: javascript

I wanna achieve an effect where users can drag the screen to switch pages. I want it to print the mouse position first.
Here's a method:

```
dragging(ev) {
    console.log(ev)
},
```

The ***dragging*** method is evoked when I press and move my mouse.

```
this.$refs.screen.addEventListener("mousedown", (ev)=>{
    this.$refs.screen.addEventListener("mousemove", this.dragging)
})
```

But when I pass some arguments into it, the ***dragging*** method can't be evoked when I do the same thing.

```
this.$refs.screen.addEventListener("mousedown", (ev)=>{
    this.$refs.screen.addEventListener("mousemove", this.dragging(ev))
})
```

I've tried several methods but I still can't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With each .addEventListener() you are creating a new EventListener ontop of all already added EventListeners. Your code would generate a new EventListerner when the mousebutton was pressed, which would create endless amounts of EventListeners on runtime.

Your second attempt doesn't work, as the EventListener got `console.log(ev)` as the callback function to execute when ever the mouse was moved.

The Approach would be to have a flag, that indicates if the mousebutton is pressed and in your mousemove EventListener you would check if the flag is true and then operate your desired logic.

```js
// Somewhere in your data property of your component
isMouseDown = false;

// When the mousebutton is pressed, we set the flag to true
this.$refs.screen.addEventListener("mousedown", (ev)=>{
    this.isMouseDown = true;
});
// When the mousebutton is released, we set the flag to false
this.$refs.screen.addEventListener("mouseup", (ev)=>{
    this.isMouseDown = false;
});

// .addEventListener expects a function, that it can execute if the Event occurs.
this.$refs.screen.addEventListener("mousemove", (ev) => {
  this.dragging(ev, arg1, arg2, arg3);
});

dragging(ev, arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  // We only execute dragging if the isMouseDown flag is true, otherwise we quit
  if(!this.isMouseDown) return;

  // You operation logic
  console.log(ev)
},
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I just found my question not so clear. May I ask how I pass more arguments to the function in addEventListener. Like: 
this.$refs.screen.addEventListener("mousemove", this.dragging(arg1, arg2, arg3)), I just found it's the key and it didn't work so well.

Comment: Yes you can. `.addEventListener()` expects a function that it can execute if the Event occurs. You can use an arrow-function to invoke your dragging function with your desired arguments. I've updated my answer to incorporate your question.